# What does the formula =cmd|'/C calc'!A0 do in Excel and why?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel 2013, on Windows 7 you can create a formula which looks like this...

```
=cmd|'/C calc'!A0
```

When you hit enter you'll get a security warning. If you ok that then you'll see that the windows calculator runs.

I believe this works for quite a few versions of excel.

It seems that cmd is running with the command line arguments /C calc, which makes the calculator run, without opening a cmd shell.

But what is the !A0 doing?

Comment: You're titles asks about the pipe `|`, but the body asks about the `!A0` part..  Can you tidy it up so they match?  It'll help clarify...

Comment: I suspect: Refers to a cell in the Excel document?

Comment: @TOOGAM, that seems reasonable, except there is no A0. It may be being used as /dev/null effectively. But if I put A1 instead excel 'corrects' the formula to =cmd|'/C calc'!'A1' when you double click. The behaviour is really quite strange.

Answer (score 3):

I think what's happening is the **`!`** does what it always does - tells excel that it's looking for something that's not on this sheet.

Usually it would be expecting a cell reference in whatever location is referenced before the **`!`**, but here, once it escapes the sheet, it goes into the file system to find the referenced workbook. And since the reference isn't the path to an excel workbook, but a command line instruction, it executes that instead and never gets to needing the cell reference after the **`!`**.

So, the A0 is completely arbitrary - I've changed it to `=cmd|' /C calc'!notthissheet` and `=cmd|' /C calc'!xxx` and it will still work.

(this is in excel 2016)

Comment: Do you know why Excel executes "cmd", rather than attempting to open it as a document?